# OpenCart: Generate QR Code After Purchase

Tags: php, opencart

I would like to generate a qr code after the customer has successfully purchased the product. I am selling tickets to music events, so the idea is that when the customer purchases the ticket, I will generate a QR code and save that QR code in the database. Our mobile app will then run the code and check if it exists in the database.

How can I generate the QR code specifically after confirmation of a purchase?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/Bacon/BaconQrCode will help?

Comment: maybe a little search would do the trick? I found this online [PHP QR](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=005)

Comment: Seems like you have misunderstood my question.

I do not have trouble generating qr codes, I have trouble implementing it to OpenCart... 

Again:

I would like to generate a qr code AFTER a customer has successfully purchased the product on OPENCART. All the tutorials I found just show you how to display the qr code on the product page, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In opencart, an order is saved in database even before it is confirmed by the customer (They are called as missing orders in case the order is never confirmed). You can see in catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php

```
$this->session->data['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($order_data);
```

This is even before the purchase has been made. So you cannot add your module in add order.

You can call your method in checkout/success.php controller. But you have to be sure that your payment method redirects to success or the user clicks on the return link after he/she completes the payment.

Another way is that you call your method before/after the function for sending new order email is called after the customer confirms the order.

Comment: In that case call your method before the line $this->cart->clear(); in success.php so that you can get the product information of the order cart before they get cleared. You can check checkout/confirm.php for code on how to get products information from cart, search for '$this->cart->getProducts()'

Comment: Also remove your email id as you can reach me here anytime if you need help :)

Comment: Also if you see for example Paypal payment, the user is redirected to Paypal for payment. If the user doesn't click on 'Return to merchant' link after payment, your qr code method won't be invoked as the user will never go to success.php, so be careful at placing your code.

Comment: Thank you so much you have been so helpful!

Okay I will attempt to do this on my own but I will definitely contact you if I am lost! 

In regards to directing the user, what if I force a header location:success.php on the paypal payment script?

Comment: You are very welcome. Please don't forget to edit your comment to remove email id. Sorry I don't have much idea about it. You can try and test if that works for you. I hope it does.